# Modify MFMessageComposeViewController UI And Send SMS Programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, sms

So I've looked everywhere and came to the conclusion that it's currently impossible to send SMS or email without using MFMessageComposeViewController (someone correct me if I'm wrong, that would be the best case scenario). Is it possible to modify the look of the MFMessageComposeViewController? My app only involves a screen with a text view where users can input text, hit the send button, and it will send it as a normal text.

Please don't mention any SMS Gateway providers, I know those exist and will resort to it if I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct - you can't send a message without invoking `MFMessageComposeViewController`. You can slightly adjust appearance of it using UIAppearanceProxy, but that's it. User will still have control over send/subject and other fields.